# How to solve this algebra expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm attempting work out why :

$$\frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}=6$$

So far I have :

$$\frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)} =$$
$$\frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(1) - (1/x)} =$$

Specifically how to simplify ? : 
$${(6x/x) - (9/x)}$$

Update :

This is a limit question, reason I did not include full equation as I was just confused how it simplified, I should really have included full equation and have taken note.

Simplify :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}$$

src :

[image]

Comment: You can simplify the equation by multipliying the numerator and the denominator by x. Your fourth line is not right. Where is the 1 at the denominator ?

Comment: Well, you can't have x = 0 but if x doesn't equal 0 you have x/x = 1, 6x/x = 6 etc.

Comment: I don't understand you last step. Why did you drop the 1? You simply multiply numerator and denominator by $x$ to get $\frac{6x-9}{x-1}$. Now that is clearly not equal to 6 for all $x$. In fact, it is not equal to 6 for *any* $x$. But it is true that the limit as $x\to\infty$ is 6.

Comment: You also can't have $x=1$. Are you sure you don't mean "solve for $x$" as opposed to prove this statement? Because if you were to plug in, say, $x=3$, you get that the expression on the left is $9/2$.

Comment: @almagest my mistake, question updated.

Comment: The tips are still valid.

Comment: @blue-sky Did you mean to put the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: @callculus what do you mean ? 'the tips are still valid'

Comment: @blue-sky I mean you still can use the tips.

Comment: @blue-sky You can simplify it to $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{6x-9}{x-1}$ and evaluate that limit, as callculus and almagest explained.

Comment: Can you just clarify right now if this is a limit problem or not? You said that you edited the question, but it looks the same to me. fleablood has a solution with the assumption that the $9$ is supposed to be a $6$ and it has already been pointed out twice that there is no solution to this equation as is.

Comment: It didn't occur to me it'd be a limit problem, but that makes *perfect* sense.  It'd be true, it'd be non-trivial, and it'd allow, the x = 0 and x = 1 exceptions.

Comment: @KevinLong yes it is a limit question, ive updated

Comment: This is not a suitable use of the Abstract Algebra tag.

Comment: Perhaps the $9$ should be a $6$.  Check the source of the problem.

Comment: @GEdgar I've updated question with source. $9$ should not be a $6$

Comment: @blue-sky The second half of fleablood's answer has the explanation you're looking for.

Comment: The initial problem was $6x - 9/x -1$ which eval to inf/inf You *put* it as ${6x/x - 9/x \over x/x - 1/x}$ to allow the x/x to reduce to 1 so we will have it reduce to ${6 - 9/x}\over{1-1/x}$ which evaluates to 6/1. You aren't doing *anyone* any favors, least of all yourself, by bringing this up in the *middle* of the problem and assuming the context isn't relevent. I thought the x/x was very weird and I wasn't sure why you weren't simply reducing them and I truly didn't get why you thought it equal 6 as ${6 - 9/x}\over{1 - 1/x}$ never *equals* 6 (which isn't what the problem asks anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to assume $x \ne 0$ and $x \ne 1$.  But if we do that we have:

$\frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}=$

$\frac{6(x/x) - 9(1/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}=$

$\frac{6 - 9(1/x)}{1 - (1/x)}=$

$\frac{[6 - 9(1/x)]*x}{[1 - (1/x)]*x}=$

$\frac{6x - 9}{x-1}= 3\frac{2x - 3}{x-1}$

which does not equal any constant.

I suspect the $9$ was supposed to be a $6$ in which case we'd have:

$\frac{(6x/x) - (6/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}= \frac{6[(x/x) - (1/x)]}{(x/x) - (1/x)}=6\frac{(x/x) - (1/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}= 6$

===

Ah... if this was a *limit* problem, that changes *everything*...

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}= $ (as we may assume $x > 0$ we have...)

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{6 - 9/x}{1 - 1/x}= $ (as we may assume x > 1, 6 -9/x and 1-1/x are continuous and 1- 1/x $\ne$ 0 we have...)

$\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 6 - 9/x}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1 - 1/x}= $

$\frac{6 - 9\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1/x}{1 - \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1/x}= $ (and as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1/x = 0$ we have...)

$\frac {6-9*0}{1-0} = \frac{6}{1} = 6$.

===

It's interesting to note that:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}= $

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{6 - 9/x}{1 - 1/x}= $

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{6x - 9}{x - 1}= $

$-9/-1 = 9$.

and

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 1^\pm} \frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}= $

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 1^\pm} \frac{(6- 9x)}{1 - x}= $

$\frac 6{\lim_{n\rightarrow 1^\pm}1-x} = \mp \infty$.

===

for all other values of $x$ (not $0$ or $1$) we have $\frac{(6x/x) - (9/x)}{(x/x) - (1/x)}=3\frac{2x - 3}{x-1}$ which can be many different values but never $6$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume a solution(s) exists. $x=0,1$ is obviously not in the domain, and we can do the following
$$
(\mathrm{EQ}) \iff \frac{1/x}{1/x}\frac{6x - 9}{x-1} = 6 \iff 6x-9 = 6x-6 \iff 9 = 6 
$$
which is a contradiction. Thus no solution exists.

---

Update:

To start with, in limits, you cannot algebraically work with the limit and the expression in the limit, like the way you seem to want to. Also the suggested solution in your textbook is somewhat odd to me.

Since the denominator and numerator have finite (non-zero in denominator) limits, then the limit of the fraction can be taken "separately/algebraically"
$$
\frac{6x - 9}{x - 1} = \frac{6 - 9/x}{1 - 1/x} \to 6, \quad x \to \infty
$$